# Laravel default error pages are different in server [minimal.blade vs illustrated.blade]

Tags: php, laravel, user-interface, laravel-5.8

I have upgraded my Laravel project from 5.6 to 5.8 (in my local before deploying to live for the first time).

Both Laravel versions are 5.8.5 installed with the same composer.json

In my **local**, the error pages (404, 503) are the illustrated ones:

[image]

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views/illustrated-layout.blade.php

however, in **live server**

> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views/minimal.blade.php

[image]

What is causing it? I want live to show the illustrated ones too with nice Go Back button.

---

Tried these but no luck :(

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: Have you run `composer update` on local, committed the new `composer.lock`, and run `composer install` on live?

Comment: yes, I upgraded the project in my local before deploying on live for the first time

Comment: Just to clarify, you *did* run composer install on your live server after the new composer.**lock** was committed? I just want to rule out a simple mistake

Comment: yes - if I try `php artisan --v` it tells me that it's 5.8.5 both on live and local

Comment: Can you include your `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`?

Comment: There is none, which falls back to `/vendor/`

Comment: Maybe your 404 blade view is cached? You can try `php artisan view:clear` on your live server

Comment: I tried that too, clearing routes, views, routes caches as well as ‘php artisan optimize’

Comment: I ran `php artisan view:clear` in my local and it changed the illustrated view to minimal view. Then I copy the files from a working project's vendor to view/errors and it worked again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like the default 404 error view in `vendor/` [changed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/83ca9a7706a8091de9da17cb687a0852c9ef1960?diff=split#diff-a9cd37e6bd1160937326e7f8e94c80bd) in Laravel 5.8 from the illustrated layout to the minimal layout, perhaps to have a less opinionated default.

I recommend creating your own view under `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php` if you want the previous view back. You can copy the illustrated view directly from the 5.7 version if that's what you wanted to display: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/views/404.blade.php

The illustrated layouts are still available, they're just not the default anymore.

Copying the old view is essentially the same as running `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors` and editing the 5 lines as @Constantin noted, but since the original was only 8 lines of code to begin with it really doesn't matter which method you chose. The basic idea is the same: explicitly define your view in `resources/` instead of falling back to the `vendor/` defaults supplied by the framework (which may change).

Comment: Do you why the change was commit?

Comment: @ZaimanNoris I don't know the reason, but my guess is that they try to keep design and style choices out of the defaults for the framework.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe late, but you could also re-publish the files from the 5.8 version without copying them from 5.7 or creating new ones:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors
```

All blade templates should be available again under views/errors.

In the views I just had to change

```
@extends('errors::minimal')
```

into

```
@extends('errors::illustrated-layout')
```

and add

```
@section('image')
<div style="background-image: url({{ asset('/svg/403.svg') }});" class="absolute pin bg-cover bg-no-repeat md:bg-left lg:bg-center">
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: You can get the svg files from here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/5.7/public/svg

Comment: this should have been the accepted answer